# DNS and domain hosting

Tags: web-hosting

I registered a domain www.xyz.com
I hosted my files at   xxx.hosting.com
Now i made a redirect at www.xyz.com pointing to xxx.hosting.com

Question:

Now when i load xyz.com the hosted index.php is loaded.

When i click on page2.php the page gets loaded but the url www.xyz.com remians same.

But it should be like xyz.com/page2.php.  How to do it? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you register a DNS CNAME entry that redirects www.xyz.com to xxx.hosting.com? Of course xxx.hosting.com would have to accept different host headers, but I assume the xxx subdomain is your own, so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a settins issue in your "Redirect" control panel. You are making it load xxx.hosting.com to load in an frame. please contact your hosting support (where u registered www.xyz.com) if you are not sure about the settings.

Note : Voted to close as it belongs to serverfault.